# SIM card contacts take time to load after turning phone on

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, micromax-a89

Device: MMX A89
Android: 4.0.4 Ice Cream Sandwich

Whenever I switch off the phone, then switch it on, SIM card contacts takes a long time to load. They don't load properly. In the call list, only phone numbers are shown and not the names associated with them.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: When you say "after switch on Android 4.0.4", do you mean you changed from a lower version to Android 4.0.4, or do you mean turning on your phone?

Comment: Turning ON (from switched off) my phone

Comment: OK, edited the title to make it clearer.

Comment: @geffchang, Any solution for that?

Comment: No idea. Did this happen only now? How about before? Are you using a 3rd pary app for contacts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's normal behaviour for the SIM card phone book, not just for Android, but on older dumbphones too. I remember my old Nokia 3310 took about a minute after booting before the phone book (and other SIM card functions) became available. The problem wasn't really noticeable on early Android phones because they took so long to boot anyway. While the phones are a lot quicker now, the SIM cards are still the same old technology.

If you want to get at them more quickly, either leave your phone turned on, or copy them to the device.

Comment: Is there any app exist which can load Sim Card contacts fast?

Comment: An app can't make your SIM card power up faster. It would be possible to make an app that caches the SIM card phone book on the device's storage, to allow faster access to it (even when the SIM card is removed), but I doubt one exists. It would just be a different way of storing your contacts on the phone instead of the SIM card.

Comment: It's basically like a desktop OS which would need to load all your programs and files and etc... It's not the world of DOS any more, where you'd just hit the switch to turn on and start working immediately and then turn it off just as fast.